# Implementing non repetitive code

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, dry

In the code for an avatargenerator I'm working on I have two button event handler methods that either makes the characters nose smaller or bigger. They pretty much contains of the same code, which I want to fix (i.e dry)

Further down you see how I've removed the logic from the event handler methods into a new function, but I've no idea how to change the actual logic inside this function so it's either making the nose smaller or bigger. So what I basically want is to be able to change - to + or the other way depending if the function it's called from the event handler method to make the nose smaller or bigger.

Any suggestions?

**The code as it's now:**

```
smallerNoseBtn.on('click', function() {

    var nose = AvGen.noses.nose1;

    if (nose.size >= 0.3) {
        nose.x += 3, nose.y += 3;
        nose.size = nose.size -= 0.1;
        nose.size = Math.round(nose.size * 10) / 10;

        nose.noseObj.transform('S' + nose.size + ', ' + nose.size + ', 0, 0, T' + nose.x + ', ' + nose.y);
    }
});

biggerNoseBtn.on('click', function() {

    var nose = AvGen.noses.nose1;

    if (nose.size <= 1.8) {
        nose.x -= 3, nose.y -= 3;
        nose.size = nose.size += 0.1;
        nose.size = Math.round(nose.size * 10) / 10;

        nose.noseObj.transform('S' + nose.size + ', ' + nose.size + ', 0, 0, T' + nose.x + ', ' + nose.y);
    }
```

**Getting rid of DRY:**

```
smallerNoseBtn.on('click', function() {
    var nose = AvGen.noses.nose1;

    if (nose.size >= 0.3) {
        changeNoseSize(nose, 'smaller');
    }
});

biggerNoseBtn.on('click', function() {
    var nose = AvGen.noses.nose1;

    if (nose.size <= 1.8) {
        changeNoseSize(nose, 'bigger');
    }
});


// The question is what to write in the functions to make it possible to use the variable
// changeSize (which will contain of either 'bigger' or 'smaller')?  

function changeNoseSize(nose, changeSize) {
    nose.x -= 3, nose.y -= 3;
    nose.size = nose.size += 0.1;
    nose.size = Math.round(nose.size * 10) / 10;

    nose.noseObj.transform('S' + nose.size + ', ' + nose.size + ', 0, 0, T' + nose.x + ', ' + nose.y);
}
```

Comment: Getting rid of DRY? Don't you mean _implementing_ DRY?

Comment: __DRY__: _Don't Repeat Yourself_. DRY code is what you _want_.

Comment: Agreed - please rephrase your question. DRY means *Don't* Repeat Yourself.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Fixed!

Comment: Also I think this might be a better fit for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: You certainly don't want to "Implement repetitive code" either!

Comment: The actual question here is _How do I use an if statement?_

Comment: @TimRogers: Sorry for not being alert today, fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass coefficient instead of changeSize and then implement something like this:

```
function changeNoseSize(nose, k) {
    nose.x -= k * 3, nose.y -= k * 3;
    nose.size += -k * 0.1;
    nose.size = Math.round(nose.size * 10) / 10;

    nose.noseObj.transform('S' + nose.size + ', ' + nose.size + ', 0, 0, T' + nose.x + ', ' + nose.y);
}
```

Then you can pass 1 and -1 as k value.

Comment: Yes, this works well except that 'nose.x -= k * 3, nose.y -= k * 3' should be changed to 'nose.x += k * 3, nose.y += k * 3' instead (that is + instead of -).

Answer (score 1):

A simple if check [ternary operator], that sets a variable if you should increase or decrease.

```
var direction= changeSize==="bigger" ? 1 : -1;
var xyChange = 3 * direction;
nose.x += xyChange; 
nose.y += xyChange;
nose.size += 0.1 * direction;
```

Personally I would pass in the direction [-1/1] instead of a string. or use an data attribute on the element.

Comment: Great one! What would you do with 'nose.y -= 3;' (same here, either + or -)?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it just like that:

```
smallerNoseBtn.on('click', function() {
    if (nose.size >= 0.3) {
        changeNoseSize([-3, -0.1]);
    }
});

biggerNoseBtn.on('click', function() {
    if (nose.size <= 1.8) {
        changeNoseSize([3, 0.1]);
    }
});

function changeNoseSize(changeSize) {
    var nose = AvGen.noses.nose1;
    nose.x -= changeSize[0], nose.y -= changeSize[0];
    nose.size = nose.size += changeSize[1];
    nose.size = Math.round(nose.size * 10) / 10;

    nose.noseObj.transform('S' + nose.size + ', ' + nose.size + ', 0, 0, T' + nose.x + ', ' + nose.y);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple `if` statement should do the trick.

```
function changeNoseSize(nose, changeSize) {
    if (changeSize == "bigger") {
        // Bigger Code

    } else if (changeSize == "smaller") {
        // Smaller Code

    } else {
        console.error('no nose size defined')
    }
    // Always run code

}
```